# Redhat Linux 6+ Opening Port 3838

Tags: port, redhat, iptables

I have tried to follow some online instructions to open port 3838 to the intranet. Basically, I added the following line after doing: `vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3838 -j ACCEPT
```

After that, I restart the iptables using: `/etc/init.d/iptables restart`

I know that if I were to comment out the similar line for 5432 in the iptables file then port 5432 would not be accessible--and so the iptables changes *are* taking effects.

But then why not a telnet command like `telnet [ip_address] 3838` doesn't work? Is it because there is currently no 'listener' process on the server yet? We did have a listener for port 3838 but because the port was not accessible on 3838 so we have the listener temporarily listening on port 80--and that works.

Is there somewhere, in addition to the iptables file, where we need to allow some firewall rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I changed the listener to listen on port 3838 and everything is working. The iptables change was needed but there was also a need for the listener to point to port 3838 before the telnet command would work.
HTH someone.
Thanks.